# how to filter two foreign keys in django

Tags: django

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor'

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='gradelevel', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    Remarks = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Student_Users}  {0.Education_Levels}'
        return suser.format(self)
class SubjectSectionTeacher(models.Model):
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='gradelevel', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    Courses= models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Sections= models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Subjects= models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Employee_Users= models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Start_Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    End_Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Remarks = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Employee_Users}'
        return suser.format(self)
```

can you guys help me on how to filter the StudentsEnrollmentRecord(Education_Levels) to SubjectSectionTeacher(Education_Levels) because it is really hard to understand the django-filter, i waste already 2 days for this error.

this is my views

```
def enrollmentform(request):
    id = request.GET.get('StudentID')
    if StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=id).exists():
      studentenroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=id)
      FeesType = SchoolFeesMasterList.objects.filter(Education_Levels=StudentsEnrollmentRecord.Education_Levels)
      return render(request, 'Homepage/enrollmentrecords.html',{"studentenroll":studentenroll,"SchoolFeesType":FeesType})
    else:
    .
    .
    .
      return render(request, 'Homepage/EnrollmentForm.html',
                    {"students": students, "edulevel": edulevel, "payment": payment, 'sched': sched, 'subj': subj,
                     "year": year, "doc": doc,"education":education,"payments":payments})
```

Comment: Can you post the error and what you tired?

Comment: when i get the student id "studentenroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=id)
      FeesType = SchoolFeesMasterList.objects.filter(Education_Levels=StudentsEnrollmentRecord.Education_Levels)"

Comment: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' this is the error what i get

Comment: please solve this problem sir, i already waste my 2days for solving this problem

Comment: Post your views.py or the function where you're having a problem.

Comment: mr Paolo, I already edit my question, i post my views

Comment: "FeesType = SchoolFeesMasterList.objects.filter(Education_Levels=StudentsEnrollmentRecord.Education_Levels)" this part what i need to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of what you posted, you're trying to find the fees, for the student record associated with the student id sent back in the get request. So in that case you want the Education_Levels from the object returned from the query, not the Education_Levels defined as a field on the model. If this isn't what you're looking to do, please clarify in the comments, and I can edit.

```
def enrollmentform(request):
    id = request.GET.get('StudentID')
    studentenroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=id)
    if studentenroll.exists(): 
        fees = SchoolFeesMasterList.objects.filter(Education_Levels__in=studentenroll.values_list('Education_Levels'))
        return # <what you want to return from these queries>
    else:
        return # <what you want to return if the records do not exist>
```

Comment: i tried your solution , and i encountered this error "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Education_Levels'"

Comment: Did you use filter or .get ?

Comment: It’s also standard convention to name your fields lower cased, for future reference. So they don’t collide with classes you may define, if the names are the same.

Comment: i use filter sir

Comment: i tried this "fees = SchoolFeesMasterList.objects.filter(Education_Levels=studentenroll.Education_Levels)" and the error become this "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Education_Levels'"

Comment: please help me sir , i already had 3days but still i didnt solve this problem

Comment: I updated the code with a filter explanation. I used .get before because I was assuming one enrollment record per student, but I may have been wrong.

Comment: sir hancho, the error change to this "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'value_list'"

Comment: typo, it is values_list